# View over several databases, how to improve speed ?

Tags: performance, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have three databases, in each database are two tables, to make the interface for the users easier I have created a view over these 6 tables and added for the database and the table a column in the view so the user can still filter if he/she only wants certain data. However I feel the performance is not as good as it could be. I feel that even though the where clause defines that for example data from db1 is not necessary the view fetches all data first and the performs the filtering. How can i make the view smart enough to avoid getting the data from db1 in the frist place in such a situation ?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a partitioned view.

You create these by specifying constraints for each of the tables in the view, so sql server will know what information is there without having to fetch it:

i.e.

```
-- On Server1:
CREATE TABLE Customers_33
  (CustomerID   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
                CHECK (CustomerID BETWEEN 1 AND 32999),
  ... -- Additional column definitions)

-- On Server2:
CREATE TABLE Customers_66
  (CustomerID   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
                CHECK (CustomerID BETWEEN 33000 AND 65999),
  ... -- Additional column definitions)

-- On Server3:
CREATE TABLE Customers_99
  (CustomerID   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
                CHECK (CustomerID BETWEEN 66000 AND 99999),
  ... -- Additional column definitions)
```

Full explanation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933141(v=sql.80).aspx